# How to override Material UI Select component MenuProps with createTheme?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I want to change all my Material UI Select component's dropdown menu style with createTheme, but it doesn't work.
[image]

Below is my code. Did I get something wrong?

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
  // palette, typography, etc.
  components: {
    MuiSelect: {
      defaultProps: {
        MenuProps: {
          PaperProps: {
            style: {
              boxShadow: '0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
            },
          },
        },
      },
      styleOverrides: {
        // do something
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your creatTheme function is ok, however I am guessing that you forgot to encompass your Material UI Select with the ThemeProvider tag, which you need to import as well.

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

         <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Select
            value={val }
            onChange={handleChange}
        >
            {data && data.map((item: any) => (
                <MenuItem key={item.key} value={item.value}>
                    {item.key}
                </MenuItem>
            ))}
            </Select>
        </ThemeProvider>
```